# In R/Shiny Understanding map function inside shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny

This is my code:

```
letters <-letters[1:5]
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  do.call(tabsetPanel,
          letters %>%
            purrr::map(~tabPanel(title = .x,
                                 uiOutput(outputId = .x)))),
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  1:5 %>% purrr::map( ~ {
    output[[paste0(letters[.x])]] <-
      renderUI({
        h1(letters[.x])
      })
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is my code. The main question here is to understand the syntax of the code inside the server function.

Why this code bellow doesn't work:

```
1:5 %>% purrr::map(
    ~ output[[paste0(letters[.x])]] <-
      renderUI({
        h1(letters[.x])
      })
  )
```

And also, for this code that works why do I need to use `{ }` inside map

```
1:5 %>% purrr::map( ~ {
    output[[paste0(letters[.x])]] <-
      renderUI({
        h1(letters[.x])
      })

  })
```

Any help to understand this syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this let's take a simpler example as this question is not related to `shiny` specifically.

```
out <- list(1:3, 5:7)
out

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 5 6 7
```

To take `sum` of each list element we can either do

```
purrr::map(out, sum)
#[[1]]
#[1] 6

#[[2]]
#[1] 18
```

Or using the `~` notation

```
purrr::map(out, ~sum(.x))
```

Now, if you want to do something "more" i.e if the function that you want to apply takes more than 1 step. So let's say, you want to take square of the summed values you need to use the curly braces (`{}`)

```
purrr::map(out, ~{
  y <- sum(.x)
  y^2
})

#[[1]]
#[1] 36

#[[2]]
#[1] 324
```

*In this simple example, I know you can do this in 1 step as `purrr::map(out, ~sum(.x)^2)` but this is just to demonstrate the use of `{}` here.*

If it get's too complex as a general rule you can always use `{}` in your functions. So in the first case for taking `sum` you may do `purrr::map(out, ~{sum(.x)})`.

Comment: thank you for your time as always. One question is this related to anonymous function: Is there an especific topic for this?

Comment: Anonymous function would be `purrr::map(out, \(x) sum(x))`. This one with `~` and `.` notation is known as formula syntax. You may read more about it in `?purrr::map` specifically `.f` argument.